# How to Make Client Server Application for BerkeleyDB using python

Tags: python, berkeley-db

Is it possible to make client server application for bekeley DB? I read that latest BDB supports Client Server access to berkeley db but can not find any examples to python module bsddb3 or bsddb any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Where did you read that python bindings of bsddb support client-server? AFAIK it support multiple processus that said it's slow. I studied for several months how to use bsddb, wiredtiger and leveldb with not success because of GIL.

Comment: berkeley is my requirement because of its tree like mechanism and i asked on oracle forums about the client server they said you can write socket application to remotely connect with berkeley there is no option otherwise

Comment: What “tree-like mechanism” are you talking about?